# Two internet connection, two routers , one home network

Tags: networking

I have two 3G routers with their respective internet connection. One internet connection gives me a public IP, so I want to use it for accessing my home network from outside, while the other internet connection has faster speed so I want to use it for all outbound internet activities.

1. Which one of the router should be used as DHCP server?
2. Will the router with DHCP server become my internet connection  for all outgoing requests?
3. How do I handle the port forwarding for accessing the internal devices from outside, if the router with public ip is not the one with DHCP server enabled?
4. How do I route all outgoing traffic via the router with high speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Assuming both routers run 24/7, it doesn't matter which one runs the DHCP Server.

2&4) You can set which Router should handle outgoing requests by setting the IP of the [standard gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) to the IP of the desired router. (You need to do this for every machine in you LAN)

3) For that you need to set up [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on on the desired router. NAT doesn't necessarily need to be on the same device than the DHCP Server.

Comment: Hi so I finally set it up and it all works. I setup the router (A) with public ip as the dhcp router and connected other router(B) via Lan. There are two other routers(C,D) connected to the router (B) via LAN and all are getting IP address from Router (A). So it's a one big happy network. Now initially when I was connecting router using Lan to Wan ports I could port forward from Router (A) into any router , but now that I am using Lan to Lan between routers I cannot get the port forwarding to work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by WAN to LAN or LAN to LAN. As I understand, your router A is your standard gateway, so if you run NAT on this router you can configure it so that specific ports are forwarded to B, C or D. It will be easier when you set up your DHCP server so that B, C and D will always get the same IP.

Comment: Lan to Wan: I connect Lan port of A to Wan port of B.  Lan to Lan : I connect Lan port of A to Lan port of B. currently it is Lan to Lan. NAT is running on Router A and all machines / router have static ip . But I cannot get to Router B from outside.

Comment: Better start a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't matter. The DHCP server doesn't even have to be one of the routers. It can be any other machine on the network. If you don't want to use DHCP at all, that'll work too. One caveat: many simple DHCP servers not only assign addresses to clients, they also push themselves as the default gateway, which should be the router with the faster internet connection.
2. Not necessarily.
3. This is unrelated to DHCP. Port forwarding works the same as always. However, incoming packets will arrive normally, but the replies will by default be routed through the other gateway. Eventually, the remote machine will receive the reply from a different source than expected and reject the packet. No connection will be established. There are ways around this, but they require advanced networking techniques that may not be available on your router configuration.
4. Set the faster router as default gateway.